# Non-default store view URL 404

Tags: magento-2.1, url, store-view, 404, url-key

I have a Magento CE 2.1.6 website, with 2 store views for different languages:

- English store view (default)
- French store view

My problem is that when I am seeing the website on one store view if I enter an URL of the other store view I will get a 404 and vice versa.

For instance, if I give any URL from the French store view to a first time viewer of the website, he'll get a 404.

The expected result would be that any URL would open its respective store view.

[Here's my website.](https://www.oliviergerardi.com)

How to solve that?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Add Store Code to Urls” in Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: It seems to have solved the problem, thank you!